# Morphia changes className when updating fields from entity subclass

Tags: java, mongodb, inheritance, entity, morphia

I have a class "Device" which is extended by a "TemperatureDevice" class.
Sometimes I need to work on the TemperatureDevice entities using the generic Device class, but after updating the data I lose all the fields declared in TemperatureDevice. Also the className is changed from org.package.TemperatureDevice to org.package.Device.

Device Class is defined as below:

```
@Entity("Device")
public class Device implements MongoEntity<ObjectId> {
   ...
}
```

TemperatureDevice Class is defined as below:

```
@Entity("Device")
public class TemperatureDevice extends Device {
   ...
}
```

Comment: attaching an executable (hopefully) test case would help showcase the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that the intended behaviour if you use `save()`? Since there is no schema, the entity fully describes the document. And the actual class name will be stored in the document.

`save()` takes the object and saves it under the given `_id`. If that field is empty a new entity will be created.

You will need to create an update query, explicitly setting the fields you want to change. Or you only access data via the full entity class.